# How to get time of page render and number of db queries in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I need to display in footer of my page 2 information:

- Rendering time
- Number of database queries

In app_dev.php these infos are in debug toolbar at the bottom of the page. Anyone knows how to get that infos in 'prod' environment?

EDIT: I found solution to first of my problems - Rendering time - under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211457/symfony2-get-execution-time) question

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in /app/AppKernel.php

Simply add `new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();` to the $bundles array.

*You'll see there's the same within  `if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test')))`*